# change python path of easy_install

Tags: python, easy-install

I am using a mac after many attempt with macports I decided to switch to regular python path, so now my python path is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

But when I install django, my mac stil use the python that Apple has installed, how do I tell easy_install to use the above python path and not the apple install python:

```
[~/mysite/djangosite]$sudo easy_install django==1.5
Searching for django==1.5
Best match: Django 1.5
Processing Django-1.5-py2.6.egg
Django 1.5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing django-admin.py script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for django==1.5
Finished processing dependencies for django==1.5
anu@localhost:[~/mysite/djangosite]$which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

I have tried which `easy_install` to see what `easy_install` getting used and its `/usr/bin/easy_install` I also went inside `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` to check easy_install but I don't find easy_install there..

```
localhost:[/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin]$ls
2to3            idle2           pydoc2.7        python2         python2.7-32        pythonw2        smtpd.py
2to3-2          idle2.7         python          python2-32      python2.7-config    pythonw2-32     smtpd2.7.py
2to3-2.7        pydoc           python-32       python2-config      pythonw         pythonw2.7      smtpd2.py
idle            pydoc2          python-config       python2.7       pythonw-32      pythonw2.7-32
```

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install*` gives nothing,

Answer (score 0):

do a `which easy_install` and make sure you get the one under `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`, or directly run the `easy_install` under that directory. After that you should install django under the directory you want.

Comment: I did which easy_install and I get /usr/bin/easy_install thats the problem I am trying to change that I have already check inside `ocalhost:[/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin]$which easy_install` but i don't see easy_install there..

Comment: what do you get when you do `ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install*`?